# DRCSIM: simulated force measurements in wrong coordinates

Tags: gazebo-sensor, contact

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If I am not mistaken, the current simulated force torque measurements are in the inertial frame (world coordinates), referenced to the center of mass of the foot.

For the DRC robot, the simulated measured forces and torques should be represented in the foot link frame (body coordinates), not in the inertial frame (world coordinates). This is how real force torque sensors work. They move with the foot, and have no idea which way is up, or North (no orientation estimate).

If you were really anal about simulating the force torque sensor, you would reference the simulated force measurements to some point (the center?) on the bottom of the foot.

Padawan Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1523/drcsim:-simulated-force-measurements-in-wrong-coordinates/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2013-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi Patrick, thanks for pointing this out.  I updated [your ticket](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/issue/155/force-torque-sensor-issues) with frame references.

Also, the high frequency noise can be filtered out with very crude low pass filtering experiment, for example,

```
      static double e = 0.99;
      physics::JointWrench wrench = this->lWristJoint->GetForceTorque(i0);
      forceTorqueSensorsMsg->l_hand.force.x  =
        e * forceTorqueSensorsMsg->l_hand.force.x +
        (1.0 - e) * wrench.body1Force.x;
      forceTorqueSensorsMsg->l_hand.force.y  =
        e * forceTorqueSensorsMsg->l_hand.force.y +
        (1.0 - e) * wrench.body1Force.y;
      forceTorqueSensorsMsg->l_hand.force.z  =
        e * forceTorqueSensorsMsg->l_hand.force.z +
        (1.0 - e) * wrench.body1Force.z;
      forceTorqueSensorsMsg->l_hand.torque.x =
        e * forceTorqueSensorsMsg->l_hand.torque.x +
        (1.0 - e) * wrench.body1Torque.x;
      forceTorqueSensorsMsg->l_hand.torque.y =
        e * forceTorqueSensorsMsg->l_hand.torque.y +
        (1.0 - e) * wrench.body1Torque.y;
      forceTorqueSensorsMsg->l_hand.torque.z =
        e * forceTorqueSensorsMsg->l_hand.torque.z +
        (1.0 - e) * wrench.body1Torque.z;
```

then the values seems more reasonable (see attached snapshot of rxplot).

[image: atlas_sandia_hands.launch]

Here's with the robot swaying back and forth:
[image: rxplots of hand hand force torque values]

Here's with the robot pinned:
[image: rxplot pinned]

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pbeeson](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/126/pbeeson/) on 2013-03-20**:
Thanks John, but here's the issue from a User's perspective.  You are doing this in the AtlasPlugin.cpp.  I don't have access to that in the competition, so I have to run such a filter on the robot machine, which requires a node of my own listening to this message at 1000Hz and publishing filtered data.  This isn't a huge issue, but if the BDI sensor has onboard filtering, this really should be done in AtlasPlugin to match the real sensor output, not by users.

**Comment by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on 2013-03-20**:
We strongly prefer that only anti-aliasing filtering be done by Gazebo. If Gazebo does filtering, this needlessly complicates whole body Kalman filtering for the robot. A simple solution is to publish both raw and filtered versions of the sensor values.

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on 2013-03-20**:
I wonder if it would help if Gazebo did internal filter based on interations (start after 80% of iterations), and published that as raw.  That might smooth out some of the unreasonable noise that we see on sensor, while retaining the "raw" per time stamp performance.  The filtering would start fresh each time step.  (The underlying assumption is that we are not having gross motions after 80% of iterations, and only converging to eliminate minor penetrations of collision objects.)

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on 2013-03-20**:
To be clear, I agree with Chris, that only "raw" sensor data should be published at 1kHz, unless the physical BDI sensor has filtering built into it.  In that case, the plugin should mimic whatever the behavior of that system is.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2013-03-21**:
How about adding a continuous first order low pass filter, off by default, but user can set the time constant (within Nyquist freq.) to activate it if desired?

**Comment by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on 2013-03-21**:
Fine with me.

**Comment by [pbeeson](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/126/pbeeson/) on 2013-03-22**:
I think the real answer is to try and model the noise as well as the real sensor.  Obviously the underlying physics plays a large part in the noise of these sensors, so until the physics settles down I think having having an option to filter noise would be good.

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on 2013-03-22**:
For the continuous filtering, I presume you are referring to output filtering.  Have you looked into the suggestion of filtering within a time step to cut down on the "noise" strictly due to physics simulation errors.  An always on filter wouldn't work for that, as I think you wouldn't want to start filtering until after the physics has stabilized a bit, and it should start fresh every time step.  The biggest issues we see are the forces/noise due to collision interactions with objects/joints.

**Comment by [John Nagle](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/395/john-nagle/) on 2013-07-24**:
The displayed forces are at a hand, not a foot, correct?  What's going on in foot forces as the robot sways?